# Looking for a function calculator

Tags: math-software, calculator

I am looking for a calculator which can calculate functions like $f(x) = x+2$
at $x=a$ etc; but I am unable to do so. Can you recommend any online calculator?

Comment: Check mark the first entry in [Function calculator](http://wims.unice.fr/wims/en_tool~analysis~function.en.html) then hit the show button.

Comment: Or use a spreadsheet (Microsoft or Open Office).

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com... you can enter the expression "f(x) = x+2 at x=a" exactly as you wrote it in your question... Personally, I would rate this site as one of the most innovative websites ever created (alongside Wikipedia, Stack Overflow (or Stack Exchange in general), YouTube and Google Maps).

Answer (score 1):

Try the [Desmos Graphing Calculator](http://www.desmos.com/calculator). The output looks really nice.

See an [interactive example of drawing lines](http://www.desmos.com/calculator/59qdbtnlzy).

Answer (score 0):

GeoGebra works well for this, eg
[http://web.geogebra.org/?command=f(x)=x+2;a=2;f(a)](http://web.geogebra.org/?command=f(x)=x%2B2;a=2;f(a))

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Calcpad online calculator for free:
Just go to http://calcpad.net/Calculator
Try to type the following example into the 'Script' box:

```
f(x) = x + 2
a = 4
f(a)
a = 6
f(a)
$Plot{f(x) @ x = 0 : a}
```

Then press 'Enter' or refresh the output to see the results